# Query about mercurial heads diagram and heads counting

Tags: version-control, mercurial

*I need to understand in which of the following lines the number of heads are change. Im finding it hard to understand what is going on in line 15.. 
I know that when a repository doesn't have the same change-sets when pulling or pushing from another repository so there is +1 head.*

**My diagram looks like this when i tried to solve it:**

Line 12: push from clone2 to main repository

Line 15: push from Clone2 to Clone1 (because r3 doesn't similar to r1)

Line 17: pull r2 & r1 from main repository, since r1 and r3 already there, i've added r2 .

Total heads created: +3

main
repository: O--------r2

```
                   \----r1
```

Clone 1:    O--------r1

```
             \---r3

             \---r2
```

Clone 2: O------r2---------r3

```
           \--r1--/
```

**The mercurial commands are below:**

1: /home/user> hg clone http://remoteserver/mainrepository clone1

2: /home/user> hg clone http://remoteserver/mainrepository clone2

3: /home/user> cd clone1

4: /home/user/clone1> echo one > a.txt

5: /home/user/clone1> hg add a.txt

6: /home/user/clone1> hg commit -m "Added a file"

7: /home/user/clone1> cd ../clone2

8: /home/user/clone2> echo two > b.txt

9: /home/user/clone2> hg add b.txt

10: /home/user/clone2> hg commit -m "Added a file"

11: /home/user/clone2> hg pull ../clone1

12: /home/user/clone2> hg push -f

13: /home/user/clone2> hg merge

14: /home/user/clone2> hg commit -m "Merged"

15: /home/user/clone2> hg push -f ../clone1

16: /home/user/clone2> cd ../clone1

17: /home/user/clone1> hg pull

Comment: This seems to be a funny course work and it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30988621/when-does-a-new-head-is-created-in-a-repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While planetmaker's answer in linked question is perfectly full and valid, I'll note some mistakes, omissions and wrong assumptions in **this** situation

1. **Clone2** got head+1 on step 11

> ```
> >hg pull ..\Clone1
> pulling from ..\Clone1
> searching for changes
> adding changesets
> adding manifests
> adding file changes
> added 1 changesets with 1 changes to 1 files (+1 heads)
> ```

2. **Main** got head+1 on step 12

> ```
> >hg push -f
> pushing to Z:\Main
> searching for changes
> adding changesets
> adding manifests
> adding file changes
> added 2 changesets with 2 changes to 2 files (+1 heads)
> ```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iT1yH.png

3. **Clone2** got head-1 on step 14
4. **Clone1** DOES NOT got head+1 on step 15 (mergeset pushed, with previous heads in Clone2 as parents of mergeset), at this step Clone1 is equal (in DAG-terms) to Clone2

> ```
> >hg push -f ..\Clone1
> pushing to ..\Clone1
> searching for changes
> adding changesets
> adding manifests
> adding file changes
> added 2 changesets with 1 changes to 1 files
> ```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/puWSH.png

5. Steps 16-17 **DO NOTHING**, because **Clone1** DAG *is fuller* than **Main** (it has mergeset from Clone2 on top of main-history)

> ```
> >hg pull
> pulling from Z:\Main
> searching for changes
> no changes found
> ```

6. In order to have full history in **Main** you must to push to it from any of clones (`-f` not needed and useless) to have mergeset as new single head in repository

> ```
> >hg push
> pushing to Z:\Main
> searching for changes
> adding changesets
> adding manifests
> adding file changes
> added 1 changesets with 0 changes to 0 files (-1 heads)
> ```

Comment: thanks for very detailed help but i wonder why in line 12 main repository doesn't have +2 since clone2 pushed his r1 and r0 before the merge.. thank very much again.

Comment: @TomerLevi - just see my first screenshot below p.2. +1 just because Main will have **2 heads instead of 1** (old head will not be head due to having childs). Check tree, I prepared screenshots,  just couldn't insert into answer with new stupid image-uploader